# Force Scaling on Orientation Change iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, mobile-safari, scale

I am working on a site that was designed and coded by someone other than myself. It was not done with the iPad and iPhone in mind. The project has now found its way to me and I've been able to make the site display well on both devices for the most part.

The part I am having trouble with is scaling on orientation change. I've tried almost all of the fixes suggested on this site and others, but none of them have worked. Basically when you load the site in either portrait or landscape it auto scales to fit in the view. This is using default behavior as I don't currently have a max/min scale size set in viewport meta.

When an orientation changes occurs, the site seems to not scale though. However, if I click a link the page will reload and scale to the correct size. I am trying to mimic this same behavior on orientation change. I have tried firing a page reload in JavaScript using the onorientationchange event, but no go. The page reloads, but does not scale. The scaling only happens when a link is clicked.

What am I missing? Is there a way to force the scaling to happen upon orientation change the same way it does when clicking a link? Is there an event that fires when a link is clicked that causes the scaling? I appreciate any help you can give me.